# How to get Ubuntu one icon onto DESKTOP

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with the Gnome desktop from the Software Center.  I just installed Ubuntu 1, but it didn't put an icon on my desktop.  How do I get one there?

Comment: Are you asking about a desktop shortcut for ubuntu one folder?

Comment: The Ubuntu design approach puts emphasis on the launcher and dash, and desktop icons IMHO lower the elegance a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that Gnome desktop doesn't use any icons.  If you need to use Ubuntu One you type in the search box "Ubuntu One" and it should be displayed to you.

Here is a nice tutorial on how to enable the desktop icons/right click though.  http://joesteiger.com/2011/07/02/enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-gnome-3-gnome-shell-ubuntu-11-04/

I don't run Gnome personally so sorry I can't be of more help otherwise I would try it out, but maybe this will get you were you need to go.

This tutorial might also prove useful for you http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/add-application-shortcuts-to-your-desktop-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Comment: I guess the best way to ask it is "How to get a desktop shortcut to the Ubuntu One folder?".

Elegant I ain't, that's why I hate DisUnity(tm).  I just want simple, quick, easy.  That means no digging through levels to find the icon in System Settings, just click and go...  That means it's gotta be on the desktop.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  If you need to find something the quickest way is hitting the "Windows Key" and start typing what you want.  We had desktop icons in the past because computers were to slow to search.  Now we can find almost any file on a computer in milliseconds.  If you need something saved in the "Ubuntu One Folder" I assume you mean making it sync in cloud storage.  If that is the case you can easily right click anything and have that sync with Ubuntu One.  Please elaborate so I can help you further.

Comment: I'm not looking to find anything.  I just need to place an Ubuntu One icon on the desktop.  I want a single "click and go", which is much faster than typing anything.  I can't drag the icon, it just sits there when I try.  I tried many different keys and clicking the icon to drag it, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Home Folder then right click on the Ubuntu One folder and in the context menu that pops up you should see an option called "Make Link" if so then click on that option. After clicking that option you should have another folder in your home folder called "Link to Ubuntu One" with a little black arrow in the lower left hand corner of the icon. You can either drag that icon to the desktop or you can right click the icon and go to the "Move to" option on the context menu and select "Desktop". This should accomplish what you asked for, it is a double click not a single click but I don't know how you could change that.

Comment: It does what you said, but not what I need.  It takes me to a directory listing, not the same Icon as you get from "Sysem Settings > Ubuntu One" icon, just like it puts on the desktop in Windoze.